# Present View Controller messing up child parent view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom container vc UI. In one of the child VC's I present a view controller as a modal.

Once it is dismissed, when I switch VC's in the navigation, I get the "must have a common parent view controller when calling" crash. Is there something about presenting a VC on top of container/child view controllers that messes up the relationship between parent/child view controllers?

Comment: Present view controller doesn't seem like a likely culprit. Do you know which VC has the bad parent? When did that VC get assigned a bad parent?

Comment: It works fine until I present the VC. I use the same code as found in the documentation regarding container VC. The problem could be that one of the VC is a property of another of the VC's. However, this works completely fine until the present is called,

Comment: Can you `NSLog` the parent of both VCs just before line which causes the crash? Which VC has the wrong parent? How did that VC get the bad value?